# http4k routes documentation

Tags: kotlin, http4k

I have an old kotlin application that uses http4k for rest endpoints.
Application is huge and there are several modules that run independently.  These modules expose `routes`  and nested `routes`.

As a person who is managing this application, I want to know what all possible routes are there and document them (if possible similar to Open API, but open API needs to define routes separately, no auto-detection).  Is there any way to crawl and check all possible routes?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://www.http4k.org/guide/reference/contracts/) already if it helps?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as Madhu. It's a bit of work, but it's worth it in my eyes (to move from normal routes to contract routes). You can do a first stab with minimal info about the API and fill that as time goes in order to generate a good open API spec file.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in main() you should have something that looks like this:

```
.toServer(app).start()
```

You could just write something like this to get an output that contains the routes:

```
print((app as RouterBasedHttpHandler).router_field.toString())
```